# how to scale a rect in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to be able to scale a Rect on android so it fits the whole screen this is my code so far: 
     public class MainView extends View {

```
private Main main;
private Rect facebook_rect;

public MainView(Context context){
    super(context);
    this.main = (Main) context;
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    Paint background = new Paint();
    background.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main_background));
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);

    Paint facebookPaint = new Paint();
    facebook_rect = new Rect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight()/5);
    facebookPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.facebook_color));
    canvas.drawRect(facebook_rect,facebookPaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getAction()!=MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    animate("facebook");

    return true;
}

private void animate(String string) {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(main, R.anim.scale_anim_1stpos);
    facebook_rect.startAnimation(anim);

}
}
```

however this : "facebook_rect.startAnimation(anim);" does not work... any ideas on how to do this?

edit: I also have this as my anim xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="3.0"
       android:pivotX="0"
       android:pivotY="0"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
       android:duration="700" android:fillAfter="true" >
</scale>
```

The effect I'm trying to achieve is something like passbook Apple's new ticket app just in case you have a better idea how to do it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scale something you can use `canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);`

The first scale factor is the amount you want to scale in X, and the second the amount in Y.

For the animation part take a look at this [link](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/09/implement-slide-in-and-slide-out.html), maybe it can help.

Answer (score 1):

First take the sceeen dimensions

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();    
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics );
```

Next find the scale factor

```
 float scale = displayMetrics.densityDpi;
```

Next scale the canvas using draw function

```
canvas.drawRect(left-20*scale, top-20*scale, right+20*scale, bottom, mPaint);
```