# How to scale-up or scale-down a Rect

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting an image from our backend. Along with the URL of the image comes the **Rect** coordinates of a particular point in the image. Now, the image is quite large so when displayed on a **ImageView**, it's scaled down.

This is where the problem comes in, the Rect coordinates sent from the backend, does not plot to the same position on the image.

Please is there anyway, I can scale down or even scale up a Rect coordinates?

I have seen answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350267/how-to-scale-a-rect-in-android) but it appears not to have a solution to the problem.

Comment: Could you please update your question and tags to say if you are using Java or Kotlin please.

Comment: @AnthonyCannon I have done that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, i've converted my code to Kotlin.

Comment: Sorry, I am using a subclass of FrameLayout with an ImageView

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you could create a function for this:

```
private fun scale(rect: Rect, factor: Float) {
    val diffHorizontal = (rect.right - rect.left) * (factor - 1f)
    val diffVertical = (rect.bottom - rect.top) * (factor - 1f)

    rect.top -= (diffVertical / 2f).toInt()
    rect.bottom += (diffVertical / 2f).toInt()

    rect.left -= (diffHorizontal / 2f).toInt()
    rect.right += (diffHorizontal / 2f).toInt()
}
```

This was an answer which I edited from [Toon Borgers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21779830/3625488).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how do I get the scale-factor pls?

Comment: It depends, could you update your question with your ImageView xml code please.

Comment: I am using a custom view to display the image. I tried using the aspect ratio (width /height) of the initial (unscaled) bitmap as the factor but it ain't working

Comment: Ok but I need to know how it is scaled when you say "when displayed on a ImageView, it's scaled down".. How is it scaled?

Comment: I am using a subclass of FrameLayout. I programmatically created the ImageView and added it as a child to the FrameLayout. So when I load the image into the ImageView with Glide, it is scaled down.